# Losing Magento customer session after save

Tags: php, session, magento, magento-1.9

I've updated to the latest Magento 1 release (1.9.4.1) and I've noticed that whenever I edit my details, after logging in, the session is recreated and I am redirected to the home page. has anyone else experienced this issue, or know how to resolve it?

I've tried disabling all modules (local and community), but the problem still remains.

I've also installed a blank version of Magento, but I get the same results.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log in to a customer account from the frontend
2. Navigate to account information page (customer/account/edit/)
3. Save account

Repeat the above steps a couple of times and eventually the session is disregarded and a new session is created in var/session, which results in redirect to home page.

Comment: Whats the value of `web/cookie/cookie_domain` in your `core_config_data` table? is it the same as your domain?

Comment: Hi, I've tried setting the cookie domain and path, but I get the same results. My original installation which is version 1.9.2.2 works just fine, but when I switch to the updated core branch I experience the issue, which resulted in me installing a fresh Magento version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I have finally found the solution!

Using Xdebug, I placed a breakpoint within the validate method inside `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`, specifically line 489.
I recalled some time back that this line gave me some bother and that there was a patch releases to fix the issue. The session was always invalidating, hence the new session creation and kick to home page.

[image]

Once I compared this file to my master branch, I noticed that line 487 was the problem!

It looks like [Patch 10570](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10570) has not been applied in this Magento version. My solution was to copy this file to the local code pool and make the change there.

I hope this info proves useful for someone!